# Typing in Chromium's/Chrome's Omnibox crashes browser

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, chrome, freeze

Very often, when I type something in Omnibox (address-bar), Chromium/Chrome crashes. W/ crash I mean that it freezes and refuses to any signals (mouse, keyboard etc.).

This is what got printed out to terminal (if browser is spawned through it):

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Arch Linux and all system is up to date. Also, I'm dealing w/ this problem for like few weeks now... so it can't be tempory bug in any package because I have upgraded browser and other related packages too. Also, I have tried to downgrade packages as well — it sadly doesn't help.

On system w/ almost the same configuration all works and browser has never crashed even once.

I'm using Awesome WM, if it matters somehow, but problem persisted also when I was using Xmonad. It seems that Firefox works, but I would like to keep using Chromium or Chrome.

P.S. If any other logs are needed, please tell me in the comments and I will update the question.

Comment: Nope, I don't think that output is related, mplayer use that lib too, but dynamically  (load if found). I use a Intel card on my laptop, each time I run mplayer I saw that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Firefox for a while, but few weeks ago I tried Chrome once again. It was a big surprise to me; it works! Seems that system upgrade had fixed the bug in some point. I'm using Google Chrome 24.0.1284.2 dev from AUR now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed nvidia-utils? (libdpau_nvidia.so is part of that package)